# matlab: delete zero rows from each matrix in cell-array without loop

Tags: matlab, loops, cell-array

I have a cell array looks like this:

```
>> celldisp(C)

C{1} = 

 4     2     7    10
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0

C{2} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0 

C{3} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 8     4     1     6
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0

C{4} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 8     4     1     6
 3     1     3     4
 0     0     0     0 

C{5} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 8     4     1     6
 3     1     3     4
 3     2     3     9
```

Now I want to delete all the rows which are filled with zeros, so I can get the cell looks like this:

```
C{1} =

 4     2     7    10

C{2} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8

C{3} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 8     4     1     6

C{4} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 8     4     1     6
 3     1     3     4

C{5} =

 4     2     7    10
 8     2     8     8
 8     4     1     6
 3     1     3     4
 3     2     3     9
```

How can I do this without any loop? 
PS: I'm trying to use

```
'cellfun(@(c_el) nonZeros(c_el), C,'UniformOutput',false)'
```

But matlab shows

```
Undefined function 'nonZeros' for input arguments of type 'double'. 
Error in @(c_el)nonZeros(c_el)'
```

so is there any brilliant way to fix the questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer mentions, you need to use `nonzeros` but even if you do that, the order of the output wont be preserved. Instead, you could

**Try this:**

```
out = cellfun(@(x) x(any(x,2),:),C,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Display the cell array using `celldisp`

```
celldisp(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the builtin function nonZeros you should type it `nonzeros` as Matlab is case sensitive. (since 2011ish).